# Zf2 "Widgetization" System correct architectural decision

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-framework2

As I search a way to implement a "widget system" using `ZF2` I found [this](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/zf2-widget-base-app-logic-td4657457.html) post.

So I would strongly appreciate to have an answer about the following questions:

1. Why `forward()` controller plugin is called "brittle"  (and "error-prone" as I read in a blog post about `zf2` widget system).
2. Is it architectural correct to write logic - that normally should be written in a `Controller` - inside a `ViewHelper`? 
     I mean: Can we instantiate a model and pass data to a `ViewModel` returning html using render(`$viewModel`) method in a `ViewHelper`?
3. If the above question is no. Can we create `Services` that will wrap this logic and call it in a `ViewHelper`?

Is this a valid way to implement a widget system in `zf2`?

Comment: Any feedback on this one ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all
@weierophinney is the creator of zf2, even if he said that forward plugin is brittle, I can't find anywhere on his github repositories (Zend\Mvc or ZendFramework) a more in depht explaination to justify this point. My guess is : with time he thought, as we often do with our code, that forward plugin is no more usefull and shoul be remove from ZendFramework. Why not ? It's may primarly opinion based.

Your second point, you should consider this :
A view helper is used to configure and render the view.
No logic has to be written in controller if its belong to the view.

For your last point : Yes ! A controller call a service. The latter call the model, and returning data, those data are given to a view or a view helper by the controller wich its return the view model (with the rendered view helper). That's all.